# Which starting conditions for the Fibonacci sequence, gives most primes

Tags: prime-numbers, fibonacci-numbers

I found the following question (at http://aperiodical.com/2012/05/matt-parkers-twitter-puzzle-25-may/):

> If you start the Fibonacci sequence 2,1 instead of 1,1 do you get more
>   or fewer primes?

Looking at the first 10 numbers, we get more primes with the modified starting conditions:

1, 1, **2**, **3**, **5**, 8, **13**, 21, 34, 55

**2**, 1, **3**, 4, **7**, **11**, 18, **29**, **47**, 76

The closed form for the normal Fibonacci sequence is
$$F_n(1,1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n - \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\frac{1- \sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^n$$

and I worked out the closed form for the modified version

$$F_n(2,1) = \left(-\frac12 + \frac12 \sqrt{5}\right)\left(\frac12 + \frac12 \sqrt{5}\right)^n + \left(-\frac12 - \frac12 \sqrt{5}\right)\left(\frac12 - \frac12 \sqrt{5}\right)^n$$

I have not been able to find an integer $n$, where the two functions intersect.

Do you have a solution to the problem, or maybe just an idea to follow?

Comment: It is wide open whether the number of prime Fibonacci numbers is finite (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_prime). If it's infinite, then one can't talk about number of primes and must instead talk about density. For reference, the second sequence is called the Lucas numbers (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number), and I don't understand what the intersection of the sequences has to do with the question about primes.

Comment: Thanks for the references. I did not know about the Lucas Numbers. My idea, was to see if the sequences became identical at some point.

Comment: They never become identical.

Comment: And the reason why they never become identical is that you can run the defining equation backwards and continue the sequence as far as you want _to the left_ in a unique way. Namely, $x_n = x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}$.